# Есть ли смысл писать на языке LOLCODE?

Tags: lolcode

Cтоит ли начинать писать на LOLCODE, какие плюсы и минусы этого языка?

Comment: Нет

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть смысл попробовать написать компилятор/интерпретатор/транслятор для этого языка. Хотя бы минимальный.

- узнаете плюсы и минусы, подводные камни.
- потренируетесь в написании компиляторов/трансляторов.

Но заниматься этим можно, если есть достаточно свободного времени, желания разобраться с ним или это тема дипломного (вполне себе тема).

Answer (score 3):

Определенно нет. Попробуйте Brainfuck

Comment: Я уже имел дело с BrainFuck. Дальше HelloWorld не уходил)

Comment: @SuperCreeper, IMHO это @Skeptik так пошутил. 

Все-таки BF и LOLCODE совсем разного уровня.

Comment: Тогда уж может лучше unlambda? Приверженцы утверждают, что она -- помогает...

Comment: @alexlz Так же могут утверждать приверженцы Brainfuck'a, что он — помогает...
Unlambda мне не понравился

Comment: @SuperCreeper, вы извращенец?) BrainFuck, LOLCODE... что дальше?

Comment: @0xFFh, а дальше Malbolge xD

Answer (score 2):

Для себя, можно. Я не думаю что это более чем любительский язык. Для разработки это несерьезно.

Answer (score 2):

Я и не знал про такое. Забавно.

```
ADD GIN TO VERMOUTH GIVING MARTINY
```

Это известный пример из Cobol, и это мне впомнилось после нескольких минут просмотра описания LOLCODE.

--

Какая-то скриптовая реинкарнация КОБОЛ-а (конечно с динамической типизацией, рекурсией и т.п.). Возможно станет популярна в определенной программистской субкультуре.

Если подходить серьезно, то учить не стоит. Кроме определенного удобства написания программ в стиле "эссе-падокафф" ничего в этом языке я не увидел.